# How to disable gnome shell extensions?

Tags: rhel, gnome

I really just need to disable gnome shell extensions, is there any way (root or normal user idc)

I've tried

```
systemctl stop gnome-shell-extensions on root
systemctl disable gnome-shell-extensions on root

sudo systemctl stop gnome-shell-extensions on normal user
sudo systemctl disable gnome-shell-extensions on normal user
```

I need to do this because I installed an extension that makes it impossible for me to work on normal user.

The problem doesn't seem to exist on root user, just normal user (probably because i haven't installed it on root user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as your root user, locate the gnome-shell extensions folder for your regular user;

```
/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

find the problematic extension and delete it's folder. then login as your regular user, as normal.

alternatively, you could disable all extensions for your user, remove the extension and then re-enable extensions.

to disable all extensions for your reguler user;

```
su - _username_ gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-user-extensions true
```

then after you've logged in and removed the problematic extension;

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-user-extensions false
```

you can also do this via dconf editor or depending on gnome version; gnome-tweaks or via the the 'extensions list' extension.

Comment: I found it, jesus! That would be you. You're jesus.

Comment: @TheWeebToBlame Don't forget to accept this answer, please.

Comment: You do not even need root if you can drop into a different TTY.